# Why is object/complex type not posted with Spring Boot command object?

Tags: forms, spring-boot, object, null, thymeleaf

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.4 and Thymeleaf 4.3.0.7.
I have an HTML page myPage.html which properly displays some values which are backed by a *MyPageForm* bean. 
This form-backing bean or (command object) has a property of type Xyz. This in turn just have two String properties `xyzKey` and `xyzValue`.
In the HTML page I have a SELECT element and the options display the text `xyzValue` and the value is set to `xyzKey`. 
This works like a charm so far.

My problem is that when I select an option and post it back to the server the 
submitted value is `null`. All other simple/primitive values of the form-backing bean are submitted properly unless 
the selected option of the SELECT element. Why does this happen and how can I solve this problem?

In tghe controller, the post mapped method is reached, but the value of subject is `null`:

```
  @PostMapping(value = REQ_MAP_CONTACT)
  public String sendContactEmail(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request, ContactForm contactForm,
      BindingResult bindingResult) {...}
```

The form-backing bean:

```
public class ContactForm {

  @NotNull
  private Salutation salutation;

  @Length(max = 40, min = 2)
  @SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE)
  @Pattern(regexp = LSMConstants.PATTERN_NAME)
  private String name;

  @NotNull
  private String subject;


  public Salutation getSalutation() {
    return salutation;
  }

  public void setSalutation(Salutation salutation) {
    this.salutation = salutation;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
  }

  public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
  }
}
```

The HTML page using Thymeleaf:

```
<form th:replace="thymeleaf/layout-common/form/form :: vf-form(
            formId='contact-form',
            formAction=@{'/kontakt'},
            formNonFieldSetElements=~{:: #contactFormElements},
            formActions=~{:: #contactFormActions})">
    <section id="contactFormElements">
        <fieldset class="form-section">
            <legend th:text="#{contact.header.form}">contact.header.form</legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <div th:replace="thymeleaf/layout-common/form/radiobutton :: vf-radiobutton-horizontal(
                            radiobuttonId='salutation',
                            radiobuttonName='contactForm.salutation',
                            radiobuttonLabelCaptionKey='common.person.label.salutation',
                            radiobuttonMandatory='true',
                            radiobuttonSize='col-sm-12',
                            labelHidden='false',
                            radiobuttonPrefix='common.person.value.salutation.',
                            radiobuttonCollection=${ {'HERR', 'FRAU', 'FIRMA'}})"
                    />
                </div>
                <select th:replace="thymeleaf/layout-common/form/select :: vf-select-object(
                 selectId='subject',
                 selectFieldName='contactForm.subject',
                 showEmptyOption='true',
                 emptyOptionKey='common.value.empty.option',
                 selectLabelCaptionKey='contact.label.client.subject',
                 selectMandatory='true',
                 selectSize='col-sm-6',
                 labelHidden='false',
                 selectCollection=${subjectList},
                 optionValue='subjectKey',
                 optionLabel='subjectText')"> </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-section">
            <legend th:text="#{common.recaptcha.header.recaptcha}">common.recaptcha.header.recaptcha
            </legend>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div th:classappend="${isReCaptchaSuccess} == false ? 'has-error' : ''">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha"
                         th:attr="data-sitekey=${recaptchaPublicKey}"></div>
                    <div th:if="${isReCaptchaSuccess} == false"
                         th:text="#{common.recaptcha.message.failure}" class="form-errorText"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" th:text="#{common.recaptcha.message.info}">common.recaptcha.message.info
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </section>
    <section id="contactFormActions">
        <button th:replace="thymeleaf/layout-common/form/button :: vf-button(
                    buttonName='sendContactEmail',
                    buttonClass='pull-right',
                    buttonLabelKey='contact.button.send')"></button>
    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: You are expecting an answer without posting actual code/configuration?

Comment: Yes, because I thought that this is a common/known problem and maybe not specific.

Comment: Your thymeleaf form isn't binding to the object. In the form you need `th:object` and in the select/input element `th:field` to bind to the correct field from the dto.

Comment: I added formBean='contactForm' to the FORM. The selectFieldName='contactForm.subject' is already bound to th:field in the background. In the controller subject is still null (as well as salutation).

Comment: No: salutation is submitted when selected but subject is not although selected.

Comment: Ok. Found it. In addition to what M. Deinum said, it would be beneficial to set the correct value to selectFieldName which should be 'contactForm.subject.subjectKey' (that is the value of the selected option) (and not only contactForm.subject).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

```
selectFieldName='contactForm.subject'
```

was incorrect because `subject` is a complex type having several properties, as we can see from the SELECT element (`key` and `value`). Since we want to submit the key of subject we have to set

```
selectFieldName='contactForm.subject.subjectKey'
```